# How to handle routing when both front end and back end are on the same server

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot and it has some services running on it. It also has a react view that has its own routing. Is this even possible, can I have a backend routing and front end routing within the same server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, front-end routing is a misleading term, although it is being widely used. The routing needs to always go to the back-end, and the back-end decides what happens with the request. If React.js, Angular or any other front-end frameworks are handling routing, back-end needs to ***forward*** all the requests that are coming from the front-end to the front-end again, which is the HTML page that has the JS and CSS. To achieve this with spring framework, I used a **tuckey** filter to forward requests to the html page. The magic word is **FORWARDING** the request to the html page.

The urlrewrite.xml for the tuckey filter forwards the requests to the ui again, it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<!-- Configuration file for UrlRewriteFilter http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ -->
<urlrewrite>
 <rule match-type="regex">
    <name>Front-end forwarding</name>
    <note>Forwarding all routes from the front-end to the ui controller</note>
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^\/([\-\w\.]+)([\-/\w\.]*)(\.([\-\w]+))$</condition>
    <from>^\/ui\/([/\-\w]+)$</from>
    <to type="forward" last="true">/ui</to> <!--This is where the ui controller is located-->
 </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

This is the tuckey filter java configurations:

```
@Component
public class TuckeyFilterConfigurations extends UrlRewriteFilter{

private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "classpath:/urlrewrite.xml";

@Value(CONFIG_LOCATION)
private Resource resource;

@Override
protected void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    try {
        Conf conf = new Conf(filterConfig.getServletContext(), resource.getInputStream(), resource.getFilename(), "");
    checkConf(conf);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ServletException("Unable to load URL-rewrite configuration file from " + CONFIG_LOCATION, ex);
    }
 }
}
```

And finally, the controller that serves the html page simply looks like:

```
@Controller
public class UiController {

  @RequestMapping("/ui")
  public String entrance(){
      return "index.html";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can have but it's always a good practice to have the routing logic at one place, as it helps a lot in troubleshooting the application once it's size grows.

***How this would work, can you give an example? When I have a front end routing to a certain link, it is always directed to the backend. I know that there is the # routing, but I'm looking for a solution for the regular "/" routing?***

You can use  [BrowserRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/BrowserRouter.md) or [StaticRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/StaticRouter.md) to achieve it. Here is the nice guide by React training team to implement Server Rendering using `StaticRouter` - [Server Rendering with React](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md).

Comment: How this would work, can you give an example? When I have a front end routing to a certain link, it is always directed to the backend. I know that there is the # routing, but I'm looking for a solution for the regular "/" routing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** add below in your pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

**Step 2,** Please add below two lines in your application.properties :

```
#reload static content lively without reboot spring boot app
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled: true

#specify the static file location
spring.resources.static-locations: file:${your-frontend-file-root-location}
```